Redefine Axios Instance generic types
I have Axios instance:
import axios from 'axios'

const $api = axios.create({
    withCredentials: true,
    baseURL: import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL
})

$api.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('access_token')}`
    return config
})

$api.interceptors.response.use((config) => {
    return config   
}, async (error) => {
    const originalRequest = error.config;
    if (error.response.status === 401 && error.config && !error.config._isRetry) {
        originalRequest._isRetry = true
        try {
            const response = await axios.get(`${import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL}/auth/refresh`, 
                {withCredentials: true})
            localStorage.setItem("access_token", response.data.access_token)
            return $api.request(originalRequest)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Not authorized")
        }
    }
    throw error
})

export default $api

When I make POST request with request type check it looks like this:
const {data} = await $api.post<ResponseType, ResponseType, RequestType>(url, request)

How to redefine Axios generic types to look like RTKQuery mutation\query types?
const {data} = await $api.post<ResponseType, RequestType>(url, request)

I tried to google some info, but found nothing related to my question.

Does this approach meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz Thank you! Unfortunately, with this implementation there is no request type-check. It allows you to pass any data without typescript validation

But I didn't change anything about that part of the typings. The original axios post() method lets you do that too. So that really seems out of scope for the question as asked... it's just the next thing you hit after getting an answer. Do you agree or disagree? If you agree I could write up an answer. If you disagree, please [edit] the question to clarify and demonstrate.
